# Не компилируется код vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Суть задачи- получить с сервера json и вывести его в listbox 
вот DTO

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Set;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private Set<String> roles;

}
```

вот код который не хочет компилироваться -хотя взят с документации vaadin

```
ListBox<UserDTO>listBox=new ListBox<>();
        listBox.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<>(userDTO -> {
            Label label=new Label("name",userDTO.getUsername());
            Label label1=new Label("email",userDTO.getEmail());
        }));
```

сразу же просит сюда `ComponentRenderer<???>`
и не видит вот эти методы

```
userDTO.getUsername()
userDTO.getEmail()
```

задача чтобы выводилось примерно так

Username:
admin

Email:
sdsds@email.com

Comment: Он не видит методы, потому что их нет. Вы их видите? Я - нет. Или научитесь готовить `Lombok`, или не используйте его вначале, чтобы не мешать мух с котлетами. В том, чтобы сгенерировать геттеры и сеттеры нет ничего сложного.

Comment: Приведите ссылку на документацию vaadin, из которой вы взяли данный пример, а также список подключенных вами зависимостей.

Comment: а что по твоему делает анотация @Data )))))

Comment: Да, серьезно? И куда же они делись тогда раз компилятор их не видит? ))) Их Ваадин съел?)))

Comment: я именно поэтому Вам и написал, чтобы вы сначала использовать его научились